# Unmount all samba file systems

Tags: linux, bash, mount

Suppose I need to unmount all samba mounted remote file systems. I can do it as follows:

```
df -T | grep cifs | awk '{print "sudo umount", $7}' | sh
```

It works but looks a bit awkward. Using `awk` to create a command and pass it to `sh` for execution does not seem *the right* way to do things.

Comment: You can skip the grep command by letting awk do that job: `df -T | awk '/cifs/{print ...}' | sh`.

Comment: I think it is more efficient to run sudo just once on the `sh` command rather than for each umount invocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs
```

would do the same thing?